# How can I make chosen item stay the same when others will be changed randomly? Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used ng-repeat directive to show names of songs from an array:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="song in ctrl.newSongs">
        <td>{{song}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Number changes here:

```
<input class="numInput" min="1" max="songs.length" required ng-model="ctrl.number" ng-change="ctrl.changeNumber()">
```

Well, here is my whole js code.

```
function Controller(CommonVariables) {
    this.number = CommonVariables.getNumber();
    this.clicked = 0;
    this.newSongs = [];
    this.localHistory = [];
    this.marked = [];
    this.changeNumber = function() {                                                                                                                                                
        CommonVariables.setNumber(this.number);
    };

    this.songEnding = function(number) {
        if (number == 1) {
            return 'song';
        }
        else {
            return 'songs';
        }
    };

    this.isInHist = function(songName) {
        this.histCheck = 0;
        for (i=0;i<history.length;i++) {
            if (history[i].indexOf(songName) > -1) {
                this.histCheck = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return this.histCheck;
    };

    this.getRandom = function(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
    };

    this.addLocalHistory = function(newSongs) {
        this.localHistory = [];
        for (i=0;i<newSongs.length;i++) {
            this.localHistory[i] = newSongs[i];
        }
    }

    this.chooseSongs = function(number) {
        this.newSongs = [];
        if (number > songs.length) {
            number = songs.length;
        }

        if (number > 0) {
            while (this.newSongs.length < number) {
                this.rand = this.getRandom(songs.length - 1);
                this.songName = songs[this.rand].name;

                if (this.newSongs.indexOf(this.songName) == -1 && !(this.isInHist(this.songName)) && this.localHistory.indexOf(this.songName) == -1 ) { 
                    this.newSongs.push(this.songName);
                }
            }
            this.addLocalHistory(this.newSongs);
        }
    };

    this.addHistory = function(newSongs) {
        this.histSongs = [];
        for (i=0;i<newSongs.length;i++) {
            this.histSongs[i] = newSongs[i];
        }
        history.push(this.histSongs);
        if (history.length >2) {
            history.shift();
        }
        this.localHistory = [];
    };
};
```

How can I make one or more songNames from `<table>` stay the same when I click on it? And make it change with others when I click it again.

Songs change when I click this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.chooseSongs(ctrl.number)">
    Refresh <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</button>
```

I tried to make a function that gets $index of clicked song and makes an array of clicked songs. Then I tried to replace songs of that indexes inside of «newSongs» array every time when I click «Refresh».

Comment: And I'm not good at Angular so I would ask you to notice that i'm using «controller as» syntax

Comment: Please provide more detail. Where is the rest of your controller code? When does 'number' change? 

Also, please refine your problem description. What is it exactly that you are trying to do, and why is your current solution not working.